# How to get different behaviour based on the value that comes from the GUI component?

Tags: java

I have text box on a GUI app where user might set two values `"productsupport" or "productLocal`"

in my service class I am checking if the type is productSupport do something otherwise do something else
Is there a better way of checking these values that come from the GUI component?

```
class ProductService{

 void handle(String type){
  if(type.equals("productSupport"){ // 
   //do something
}
else if(type.equals("productLocal"){
//do something else
}
}

}
```

Comment: This looks fine. What issues are you having?

Comment: I dont like the way I am hard coding values in service class

Comment: Then don't? Use an enum class?

Comment: What library or platform are you using? Is it javafx or swing or awt or something similar...

Comment: Its also pretty common to hardcode string as constants... then use a switch

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what kind of UI it is, but in general I would not use a textbox in case a user can choose between two things. It would make more sense to use a drop-down or combo box. As items in the boxes I would use the values of an enum:

```
enum Type {
    PRODUCT_SUPPORT("Product support"),
    PRODUCT_LOCAL("Product local");

    final String label;

    Type(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

```
class ProductService {
    void handle(Type type) {
        switch(type) {
            case PRODUCT_LOCAL:
                //do somethinf
                break;
            case PRODUCT_SUPPORT:
                //do something els3
        }
    }
}
```